# Rendering images from an API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div class="row box">
  <div class="col-md-4 pic"></div>
  <div id="temperature" class="col-md-4 change make_blue bigger_text">
    Placeholder
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button id="getChange" class="make_orange bigger_text">Change units</button>
  </div>
</div>
$(document).ready(function() {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
var url = "https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=" + position.coords.latitude + "&lon=" + position.coords.longitude;
   $.ajax({
     url:"https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=" + position.coords.latitude + "&lon="+ position.coords.longitude,
    success: function(data) {
        var temp = data.main.temp;
        var icon = data.weather[0].icon;
        $(".pic").html(icon);
        $(".change").html(temp);
      $("#getChange").on("click", function() {
        $(".change").html(temp);
        $("#temperature").html(changeTemp(temp));
   });
      }
    });
 });
});
```

I'm having trouble rendering the "icon" variable into the element with id="pic". Any suggestions to make it work? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this for the image:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = icon;
$(".pic").append(img);
```